# How do I show only a part of the compiled text in the output pdf?

Tags: compiling

I want to compile my whole tex file ( made with texmaker), but that the resulting pdf would show only a part of it ( say, one specific page I want to print).

I cannot simply comment out the other parts, because I need to keep the \section count, among other things.

The closest answer I found on this site was to hide the stuff in a \vbox, but I struggle to define an adequate environment : I tried

`\newenvironment{\hide}{\setbox0\vbox\bgroup}{\egroup}`

but it will not compile, and I lack the latex insight to see what is wrong with that.

Notice that my dream will be an environment for the code I want to *show*, like :

```
% Heading

    \begin{document}

Stuff I want to compile, but not print 

\begin{show}
The stuff I want in my pdf 
\end{show}

Some other stuff 
\end{document}
```

Is there anything close that already exist ?

Edit : I know I can print the desired page as a pdf afterwards, but the issue will come often, so I would like to avoid the extra manipulation.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Welcome. // You could print only the specific page, e.g. to a pdf printer. Does that meet your requirement? Or do you want to black it out, like in secret documents?

Comment: Since I intend to do this on a regular basis, I would like to avoid the use of a pdf printer. Having a command inside my document I can juste move around/comment out seems way more efficient !

Comment: I usually compile the entire document, open the resulting pdf with Chrome, then print > Save as PDF;  Pages > Custom and choose pages to print.

Comment: A different approach: Options > Configure texmaker > Quick build. Select "User". In the blank put something like: `pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -jobname %-tmp %.tex | pdfjam %-tmp.pdf 5 -o %.pdf`. (That'll output just page 5; change 5 to whatever else you want, or a range, or whatever.) But depending on  your actual use case, which you haven't described, you might be able to do even better/more useful things.

Comment: You can add whatever it suggests by the Wizard for "Pdf Viewer" (different for different operating systems) after another `|` at the end of the command if you want it to refresh the viewer when Quick Building as well.

Comment: This should do for printing a specific page/range of pages, which would be my main use. Thanks !

Do you now what -interaction=nonstopmode do ? That is the only part I cannot guess.